# Best way or library for lazy lading image in asp core razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, lazy-loading, c#-3.0

I want to use from image in asp core razor page but image loading is late?
best way to load ?

Comment: what do you mean by "but image loading is late"?

Comment: when get  data like id,title,image_url  from an  api  image show in <img />  it is  takes time

Comment: Yes of course it takes time to load. You can speed it up by 1. upgrade your bandwidth. 2. Move your server closer to your clients. 3. Use CDN. 4. Optimize your images.